# HR after a input from a guestlist

Tags: php, html

I was busy working on something I had to do for school. I had problems getting the `<hr>` tag in the right place. The exercise is to place it after every entry, but I can only seem to get it in front of every entry. This is the code where I change the `<hr>`:

```
<?php
    $bestandsnaam = "gastenboek.txt";
    // aantal regels per bijdrage om in te lezen
    // elke bijdrage bestaat uit 5 regels
    $aantal_regels = 5;
    // teller om bij te houden hoeveel regels
    // zijn gelezen
    $teller = 0;
    // Aantal bijdragen wordt bijgehouden.
    $aantal_bijdragen = 0;
    // gastenboek openen om te lezen
    if (file_exists($bestandsnaam)){
      $fp = fopen($bestandsnaam, "r");
    }
    else{
      echo "<h2>Het gastenboek is nog leeg!</h2>
      <a href= 'gastenboekschrijven.php'>
      Wees de eerste die erin schrijft!</a> ";
      exit;
    }
    while (!feof($fp)){
      $regel = fgets($fp);
      if (!feof($fp)){
        if ($teller % $aantal_regels == 0){
        // kop afdrukken
        $aantal_bijdragen++;
        echo "<h3>Bijdrage: $aantal_bijdragen</h3>";

        echo "<hr>";
        }
      }
      // regel afdrukken
      echo "$regel <br>";
      $teller++;
    }
    echo "<a href='opdracht32.php'>Terug naar de homepage</a>";
  ?>
```

and the place where it saves my entry:

```
fputs($fp, "Datum: ".$datum);
fputs($fp, "\n");
fputs($fp, "Naam: ".$_POST["naam"]);
fputs($fp, "\n");
fputs($fp, "E-mail adress: ".$_POST["email"]);
fputs($fp, "\n");
fputs($fp, "Woonplaats: ".$_POST["woonplaats"]);
fputs($fp, "\n");
fputs($fp, "Uw bericht: ".$_POST["bericht"]);
fputs($fp, "\n");
fputs($fp, "\n");
fclose($fp);
echo "<h2>Klaar</h2>";
echo "<p>De bijdrage is opgeslagen</p>";
echo "<a href = 'opdracht32.php'>Terug naar het beginscherm</a>";
```

I was wondering if someone could help me.

Best wishes for the holidays!

Comment: What do you mean by "hr". Is it `<hr>` tag ?

Comment: Yes i mean <hr> tag sorry this is my first time asking something on this platforrm

Comment: Consider using a CSS borders; it's less HTML